RabbitMQ errors with: "missed heartbeats from client, timeout: 60s"
I have written some rust code to send and receive messages from a RabbitMQ message queue.
The send process pushes to the queue on data from a socket connection. The receive is just waiting on the RabbitMQ Channel awaiting a message.
After 60 seconds of no activity on the queue the docker container reports the error:
2024-05-16 06:42:51.216258+00:00 [error] <0.3164.0> missed heartbeats from client, timeout: 60s
The receive.exe is still waiting without the heartbeat timeout.
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        while let Some(msg) = rx.recv().await {
            if let Some(payload) = msg.content {
                println!(" [x] Received {:?}", str::from_utf8(&payload).unwrap());

                let ack_args: BasicAckArguments = BasicAckArguments {
                    delivery_tag: msg.deliver.unwrap().delivery_tag(),
                    multiple: false
                };

                ch.basic_ack(ack_args).await.unwrap();
            }
        };
    });

The send.exe creates a connection and a channel and stores them for use on the socket data coming in.
pub async fn send_rabbit_mq_message(rabbit_mq: &RabbitMQ, queue_name: String, message: String) {

    let q_args = QueueDeclareArguments::default()
        .queue(String::from(queue_name))
        .durable(true)
        .finish();
    let (queue_name, _, _) = rabbit_mq.channel.queue_declare(q_args).await.unwrap().unwrap();

    let payload = String::from(message.to_string()).into_bytes();
    let publish_args = BasicPublishArguments::new("", &queue_name);
    // publish messages as persistent
    let props = BasicProperties::default().with_delivery_mode(DELIVERY_MODE_PERSISTENT).finish();
    rabbit_mq.channel.basic_publish(props, payload, publish_args).await.unwrap();
    //rabbit_mq.channel.confirm_select(ConfirmSelectArguments::new(true)).await.unwrap();

    println!("On '{queue_name}' -> '{message}'");
}

I am using the amqprs crate.
How do I trigger/allow or respond to the heartbeat to keep channel and connection alive?
pub async fn rabbit_mq_connect(config: &RabbitMQConfig) -> Connection {

    let conn = Connection::open(&OpenConnectionArguments::new(
        config.server.as_str(),
        config.port,
        config.uid.as_str(),
        config.pwd.as_str(),
    )).await.unwrap();

    let heartbeat = conn.heartbeat();

    println!("conn.heartbeat() = {heartbeat}");

    return conn;
}

What other information is required to get the appropriate help?

You just need to set the heartbeat setting when creating the connection, you can see an example how this is done from a amqprs test https://github.com/gftea/amqprs/blob/main/amqprs/tests/test_heartbeat.rs

Checkout https://github.com/gftea/amqprs/blob/main/amqprs/src/api/connection.rs. From what I can see the heartbeat is being set to 60 in my scenario.
